# Enable print for static file access

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I m using UseStaticFiles for static file serving. But I want to test when it serving or downloading my file?

My code is:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                   Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "RBFirmware")),
    RequestPath = "/File"
});

Console.WriteLine("downloading --");
```

in Startup.cs, But this downloading print comes to the only startup.

I want "Console.WriteLine" log when /file folder accessed?

Comment: This code tells ASP.NET Core that browsers can request static files from that path. It doesn't upload or download anything.

Comment: What is your *actual* question? How to log static file access? ASP.NET Core already logs requests through its logging infrastructure. You should already receive log notifications for downloads in the console.

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos yap.but i can access my file from this path  <ip>//File/myfile   by using UseStaticFiles.right ?
is it possible to get any log for that file access

Comment: Don't you *already* get a log entry about this in the console? BTW which ASP.NET Core version are you using?

Comment: no .i wrote this code in Startup.cs

Comment: version netcoreapp2.0

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos
https://192.168.2.1:44321/File/r_1_3.bin

i can access my file folder using this endpoint .That means i run my code and i got the ouput right ?

But while accessing there is no console log is coming.thats is my problem

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Your `Console.WriteLine` line is only going to run once, at startup, because `Startup` only runs once. What is it that you expect to happen? FWIW, all requests are logged automatically at the info level. You can send those logs wherever you like.

Comment: @ChrisPratt..ya .you are right.
.i didn't understand what is info level means?

Answer (score 1):

For `app.UseStaticFiles`, you may try `OnPrepareResponse` to show up this file is processing like

```
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
               Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "RBFirmware")),
            RequestPath = "/File",
            OnPrepareResponse = context => {                    
                Console.WriteLine($"downloading -- {context.File.Name}");
            }
        });
```